# Random sampling a large Cartesian product of iterables

Tags: python, random, cartesian-product

I have multiple iterables and I need to create the Cartesian product of those iterables and then randomly sample from the resulting pool of tuples. The problem is that the total number of combinations of these iterables is somewhere around 1e19, so I can't possibly load all of this into memory.

What I thought was using `itertools.product` in combination with a random number generator to skip random number of items, then once I get to the randomly selected item, I perform my calculations and continue until I run out of the generator. The plan was to do something like:

```py
from itertools import product
from random import randint

iterables = () # tuple of 18 iterables
versions = product(iterables)

def do_stuff():
    # do stuff

STEP_SIZE = int(1e6)

# start both counts from 0. 
# First value to be taken is start + step
# after that increment start to be equal to count and repeat
start = 0
count = 0

while True:
    try:
        step = randint(1, 100) * STEP_SIZE

        for v in versions:
            # if the count is less than required skip values while incrementing count
            if count < start + step:
                versions.next()
                count += 1
            else:
                do_stuff(*v)
                start = count             
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Unfortunately, `itertools.product` objects don't have the `next()` method, so this doesn't work. What other way is there to go through this large number of tuples and either take a random sample or directly run calculations on the values?

Comment: What is the size of each iterable?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, At the moment about 10 elements each but there's 18 of them.

Comment: @KellyBundy, sorry I corrected the post.

Comment: Your `step` is on average 50 million, so... You want your sample size to be around 200 billion tuples?

Comment: @KellyBundy, yeah, agree. The current `STEP_SIZE` is just for testing. I should probably increase it to at least 1e10 or 1e11.

Comment: Should btw rather be `step = randint(1, 100 * STEP_SIZE)`. (If this random-skip approach were reasonable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Python are you using? Somewhere along the way `.next()` methods were deprecated in favor a new `next()` built-in function. That works fine with all iterators. Here, for example, under the current released 3.10.1:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> itp = itertools.product(range(5), repeat=6)
>>> next(itp)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> next(itp)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
>>> next(itp)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2)
>>> next(itp)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3)
>>> for ignore in range(50):
...     ignore = next(itp)
>>> next(itp)
(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4)
```

Beyond that, you didn't show us the most important part of your code: how you build your product.

Without seeing that, I can only guess that it would be *far* more efficient to make a random choice from the first sequence passed to `product()`, then another from the second, and so on. Build a random element of the product from one component at a time.

### Picking a random product tuple efficiently

Perhaps overkill, but this class shows an especially efficient way to do this. The `.index()` method maps an integer `i` to the i'th tuple (0-based) in the product. Then picking a random tuple from the product is simply applying `.index()` to a random integer in `range(total number of elements in the product)`.

```
from math import prod
from random import randrange

class RanProduct:
    def __init__(self, iterables):
        self.its = list(map(list, iterables))
        self.n = prod(map(len, self.its))

    def index(self, i):
        if i not in range(self.n):
            raise ValueError(f"index {i} not in range({self.n})")
        result = []
        for it in reversed(self.its):
            i, r = divmod(i, len(it))
            result.append(it[r])
        return tuple(reversed(result))

    def pickran(self):
        return self.index(randrange(self.n))
```

and then

```
>>> r = RanProduct(["abc", range(2)])
>>> for i in range(6):
...     print(i, '->', r.index(i))
0 -> ('a', 0)
1 -> ('a', 1)
2 -> ('b', 0)
3 -> ('b', 1)
4 -> ('c', 0)
5 -> ('c', 1)
>>> r = RanProduct([range(10)] * 19)
>>> r.pickran()
(3, 5, 8, 8, 3, 6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 2, 0, 5, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 2)
>>> r.pickran()
(4, 5, 0, 5, 7, 1, 7, 2, 7, 4, 8, 4, 2, 0, 2, 9, 3, 6, 2)
>>> r.pickran()
(8, 7, 4, 1, 3, 0, 4, 6, 4, 3, 9, 8, 5, 8, 9, 9, 7, 1, 8)
>>> r.pickran()
(8, 6, 6, 0, 6, 7, 1, 3, 9, 5, 1, 4, 5, 8, 6, 8, 4, 9, 9)
>>> r.pickran()
(4, 9, 4, 7, 1, 5, 5, 1, 6, 7, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 9, 1, 7, 0)
>>> r.pickran()
(3, 0, 3, 9, 8, 6, 3, 0, 3, 0, 9, 9, 3, 5, 2, 3, 7, 8, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the deprecation of `next()` method.

Comment: Note that I added an especially efficient way of implementing my suggestion. @BrokenBenchmark's way is fine, but if you're going to do a lot of this, repeated `divmod()` is a lot cheaper than repeated `random.choice()`.

Comment: Hmm, from "a lot" cheaper and all that effort I rather expected a bigger speed advantage than the factor 1.5 that I observe:

Comment: https://tio.run/##tVNNa9xADL3vrxCBkJlg3Gy3lCSQY@@lh16WxUxsuStij4cZObSE/PatZmb9seTSSwXGtuZJek/SuD98HOzu3vnTqfVDD0w9EgP1bvAMHh0a3qST3vBx8js/NNnrjW3kNeHlT55fWEB9HKjGzabuTAjww9jvEjPW/LgBsQZbqCqyxFWlAnZtAcTozXOHQWdItHhSEgd4go4Cq944FT/WaH2JtoKN9DIWbTEnEeRcm2yDv6fCq4IkR2AHaYCFJETlpCtING8oIPw03YjfvB@8aq9SRnij98vwtxz/rq8Wnh7D2LHw3B9mXzt4oByHr@gDNmrmfVmbCvAS29BrLyrlT0Qq4lUflhqlcQ6toHjvD2sCPHoLPLoO1Vwvh6y75Kh@ERmJyYrFOTzzS42c5z61S38c/Of/MPl/ZJqFxhR5Ky93Ira@Wia2O8dH90vSIEeLjOKjpGh27J8xzmV7Jza7k4AgVyP1N14mlXKqfS62vdMHuIXtgy7PEopzqqf80nr/uFvWxHmyrG7VzfWXctvCGG7gGhTDp4mA5MKvOpFP2yQSiyyjrCpreqyqvAc5kz6d/gI

Comment: And even another factor 1.5 faster: [pre-producing up to four iterables](https://tio.run/##TVFLboMwEN1zitlEsVNEg4iqNlLuUHWLkOXA0FgBY9nDoqen/hCS2VjyG7@fzR/dJl19GrssvZ1GIDWiIlCjmSyBRYOSsohYqTt/rEh7m1SLCVGElqZpcA/Q2KmbW8r9llQ6y9pBOgc/Un8noDpn4KfDHoRQWpEQzOHQ55FKXgd0PK2ECUihyMEF6kE5Yis9O2zbtTqrt1PD@fbodfrJggKlQ4RfZMccBtTsKZXDiTfZZsmo9u43o6MXGxZpthpoNgOyGKwI6cWDh43SsFRLvnnm3lIW9MVTv1pJw/U9NuOhl3Lyp6aexytaH7w8@tmuYxfON40dS1/EIhGrk0J55A0coPzixRomX6ku6eC8PlfNxmes0r5Ott@dirKH2e1hB4zg/WHAc@EHj44puKVQWpQshNByRCFS9YmJL8s/)

Comment: @KellyBundy, "all that effort"? It was easy ;-) It doesn't change `O()` behavior, but a factor of 1.5 is fairly called "a lot" for an improvement in constant factor. As to "pre-producing up to four iterables", fine by me if the OP prefers that . That also increases the data burden by a factor of thousands, to pre-compute and save away 10000-element partial products.

Comment: Well, compared to the alternative it's a lot more. More than 1.5 times more code/typing :-). Their desired sample size seems to be hundreds of millions, so some tens of thousands of shorter tuples seem insignificant. Your indexing (possibly combined with "pre-producing") might be good for that actual bigger sampling, though, I think it's faster to sample hundreds of millions of ints than hundreds of millions of tuples (if one wants to avoid duplicates).

Comment: If they want a large sample without duplicates, `random.sample(range(self.n), k)` gets `k` suitable integers directly, which can then be passed to `index()` to get unique tuples. If they generate tuples directly, they'll need instead to implement some kind of iterative accept/reject method, to guarantee `k` unique tuples. The "use integers" approach is general and easy to build on.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to generate the Cartesian product. Sample from one iterable at a time to generate your result using `random.choice()`. The number of elements across all iterables is small, so you can store all the elements in memory directly.

Here's an example using 18 iterables with 10 elements each (as specified in the comment):

```py
import random

iterables = [list(range(i, i + 10)) for i in range(0, 180, 10)]
result = [random.choice(iterable) for iterable in iterables]
print(result)
```