# How do i optimize code when the execution time is too slow?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, time, execution

I have this Python code, but it's already running for 24h and doesn't seem to print the result for now.
I don't know how long it will take.
Can someone help me to optimize this code?
The code is to find the best performance for trading RSI divergence in a certain period.
It first defines some parameters for the RSI.
The code then goes through every possible combination to find the best combination of parameters to have the best performances.
I'm not really an expert.

I don't really know how i can change the code as i'm no expert.
Happy to learn.

Thank you guys.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ta

def load_data(file_path, start_date, end_date):
    """
    Loads data for the specified symbol and date range from a CSV file
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    if 'Date' not in df.columns:
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df = df.set_index('Date')
    df = df[(df.index >= start_date) & (df.index <= end_date)]
    return df

def calc_rsi(df, n):
    """
    Calculates the relative strength index (RSI) for the given dataframe and window size
    """
    delta = df["Close"].diff()
    gain = delta.where(delta > 0, 0)
    loss = abs(delta.where(delta < 0, 0))
    avg_gain = gain.rolling(window=n).mean()
    avg_loss = loss.rolling(window=n).mean()
    rs = avg_gain / avg_loss
    rsi = 100 - (100 / (1 + rs))
    return rsi

def calc_pivot_point(df, pivot_point_type, pivot_point_n):
    """
    Calculates the pivot point for the given dataframe and pivot point type
    """
    if pivot_point_type == "Close":
        pivot_point = df["Close"].rolling(window=pivot_point_n).mean()
    elif pivot_point_type == "High/Low":
        pivot_point = (df["High"].rolling(window=pivot_point_n).mean() + df["Low"].rolling(window=pivot_point_n).mean()) / 2
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid pivot point type")
    return pivot_point

def calc_divergence(df, rsi, pivot_point, divergence_type, max_pivot_point, max_bars_to_check):
    """
    Calculates the divergence for the given dataframe and parameters
    """
    if divergence_type == "Regular":
        pivot_point_delta = pivot_point.diff()
        pivot_point_delta_sign = pivot_point_delta.where(pivot_point_delta > 0, -1)
        pivot_point_delta_sign[pivot_point_delta_sign > 0] = 1
        rsi_delta = rsi.diff()
        rsi_delta_sign = rsi_delta.where(rsi_delta > 0, -1)
        rsi_delta_sign[rsi_delta_sign > 0] = 1
        divergence = pivot_point_delta_sign * rsi_delta_sign
        divergence[divergence < 0] = -1
        divergence = divergence.rolling(window=max_pivot_point).sum()
        divergence = divergence.rolling(window=max_bars_to_check).sum()
        divergence = divergence.where(divergence > 0, 0)
        divergence[divergence < 0] = -1
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid divergence type")
    return divergence

def backtest(df, rsi_period, pivot_point_type, pivot_point_n, divergence_type, max_pivot_point, max_bars_to_check, trailing_stop, starting_capital):
    """
    Backtests the strategy for the given dataframe and parameters
    """
    rsi = calc_rsi(df, rsi_period)
    pivot_point = calc_pivot_point(df, pivot_point_type, pivot_point_n)
    divergence = calc_divergence(df, rsi, pivot_point, divergence_type, max_pivot_point, max_bars_to_check)
    positions = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=["Position", "Stop Loss"])
    positions["Position"] = 0.0
    positions["Stop Loss"] = 0.0
    capital = starting_capital
    for i, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
        date = row[0]
        close = row[1]["Close"]
        rsi_val = rsi.loc[date]
        pivot_val = pivot_point.loc[date]
        divergence_val = divergence.loc[date]
        if divergence_val > 0 and positions.loc[date]["Position"] == 0:
            positions.at[date, "Position"] = capital / close
            positions.at[date, "Stop Loss"] = close * (1 - trailing_stop)
        elif divergence_val < 0 and positions.loc[date]["Position"] > 0:
            capital = positions.loc[date]["Position"] * close
            positions.at[date, "Position"] = 0.0
            positions.at[date, "Stop Loss"] = 0.0
        elif close < positions.loc[date]["Stop Loss"] and positions.loc[date]["Position"] > 0:
            capital = positions.loc[date]["Position"] * close
            positions.at[date, "Position"] = 0.0
            positions.at[date, "Stop Loss"] = 0.0
    return capital

def find_best_iteration(df, start_rsi_period, end_rsi_period, pivot_point_types, start_pivot_point_n, end_pivot_point_n, divergence_types, start_max_pivot_point, end_max_pivot_point, start_max_bars_to_check, end_max_bars_to_check, start_trailing_stop, end_trailing_stop, starting_capital):
    """
    Finds the best iteration for the given parameters
    """
    best_result = 0.0
    best_params = None
    for rsi_period in range(start_rsi_period, end_rsi_period + 1):
        for pivot_point_type in pivot_point_types:
            for pivot_point_n in range(start_pivot_point_n, end_pivot_point_n + 1):
                for divergence_type in divergence_types:
                     for max_pivot_point in range(start_max_pivot_point, end_max_pivot_point + 1):
                        for max_bars_to_check in range(start_max_bars_to_check, end_max_bars_to_check + 1):
                            for trailing_stop in np.arange(start_trailing_stop, end_trailing_stop + 0.01, 0.01):
                                result = backtest(df, rsi_period, pivot_point_type, pivot_point_n, divergence_type, max_pivot_point, max_bars_to_check, trailing_stop, starting_capital)
                                if result > best_result:
                                    best_result = result
                                    best_params = (rsi_period, pivot_point_type, pivot_point_n, divergence_type, max_pivot_point, max_bars_to_check, trailing_stop)
    return best_result, best_params

# Define the parameters
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\The Death\\Downloads\\Binance_BTCUSDT_spot.csv'
start_date = "2020-03-16"
end_date = "2021-04-12"
df = load_data(file_path, start_date, end_date)

def load_data(start_date, end_date):
    # Your code to load the data for the specified date range
    # ...
    return df

# Define the parameters for the backtesting
start_rsi_period = 1
end_rsi_period = 30
pivot_point_types = ["Close", "High/Low"]
start_pivot_point_n = 1
end_pivot_point_n = 50
divergence_types = ["Regular"]
start_max_pivot_point = 1
end_max_pivot_point = 20
start_max_bars_to_check = 30
end_max_bars_to_check = 200
start_trailing_stop = 0.01
end_trailing_stop = 0.5
starting_capital = 10000

# Run the backtesting
df = load_data(start_date, end_date)
best_result, best_params = find_best_iteration(df, start_rsi_period, end_rsi_period, pivot_point_types, start_pivot_point_n, end_pivot_point_n, divergence_types, start_max_pivot_point, end_max_pivot_point, start_max_bars_to_check, end_max_bars_to_check, start_trailing_stop, end_trailing_stop, starting_capital)


# Print the results
print("Best result: ", best_result)
print("Best parameters: ", best_params)
```

Comment: Your `backtest` function is using `iterrows()` which is a no-no if you want any kind of performance. You should at the very least, put the contents of the for-loop into a function and then use `df.apply()`. In `find_best_iteration` rather than plain iterating over iterables, select a combination of values and use that combination, then pick the next one and so on. See the question and the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71331668/random-sampling-a-large-cartesian-product-of-iterables/71331746#71331746

Comment: Also, print status messages during the runtime so that you know how many options you went through and how many remains. And, of course, for a code like this it's best to test and optimise it before setting to run for 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I have two recommendations after I scroll up your code:

1. Reduce the usage of for loop. As you increase a layer of for loop (initial is O(n), the time complexity of your code will increase by a power. In your find_best_iteration() there is about 7 layers of for loop, this is extremely cost your time.
2. Save and process your data in numpy.array() instead of pd.dataframe(). Dataframe is a class that contains too many unused attributes, and its performance is also slower than numpy.array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods to improve the performance:

- The `backtest()` function is used many times inside the `find_best_iteration()` function under many `for` loops, thus the `positions` variable inside `backtest()` is being updated frequently which can be show when the `positions` variable is a Dataframe. You can consider using numpy array for the `positions` variable that is optimized for updates.
- You can try using the `multiprocessing` module in Python to parallelize the calculation of the `divergence` variable.

Hope this help!